# Getting jitters in my collision detection

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

So I'm doing a simple collision detection where the player is moved downward 3 every time it's updated and not on the ground, but when it is on the ground it moves the difference of it's position, and the grounds. But I'm getting jitters (It's moving down and up too much, and not being perfectly at a standstill).

My question is: How do I make this code calculate the difference properly?

```
Vector3f pos = new Vector3f(25,-50,25);
//Vector3f pos = new Vector3f(25,-50,25); isn't actually in the update method, 
//but is in the object's constructer.

onGround = false;

Vector3f projPos = new Vector3f(pos);
projPos.y += fallSpeed;
//get a vector of all the triangles touching the player
Vector<Tri> tris = getTrisTouching(pos);

float minY;

//make it so if we don't have a list we don't get tossed into infinity
if(tris.size() > 0) minY = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
else minY = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < tris.size(); i++){
    Tri tri = tris.get(i);
    if(projPos.y + radius <= tri.max.y){

        float difference = tri.min.y - projPos.y;
        if(difference < minY) minY = difference;
        onGround = true;
    }
}

if(onGround){
    pos.y = minY;           
}

else{
    pos.y = projPos.y;
}
```

Comment: It kind of looks like your always assuming your not on the ground and then checking if you are? I can't tell too much from your code but I think you need to change you approach to find a simpler method to tell if your on the ground, and then only do the fall/collision method if your not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your collision detection code (the 3 lines inside the first 'if' statement) is confusing but let's assume that when you're on the ground, the player doesn't touch any triangles (since it might be 1 pixel above them), so next frame you are moved down, then next frame you are moved back up.

A fix maybe would be to use projPos inside your for-loop instead of the actual position.

Comment: Okay, I changed the code to whats in the question now (I updated the question's code to the current code) and I'm still falling through the floor.

Comment: I don't see how it makes any sense to set the player's position as the difference between the closest triangle and the player.

Comment: Also, you may want to use projPos for 'getTrisTouching' too. ;)
And that if statement inside the for loop will _always_ be true considering that you are getting a list of triangles that touch the center ;)